# How to check if a driver for ubuntu exists for a chinese unbranded air mouse and keyboard?

Tags: drivers, usb, keyboard, mouse

I would like to use my unbranded chinease "air mouse + keyboard", that I normally use at home connected to an android tv, on a Ubuntu 16.04 laptop at work for making presentation annotations.

Basically, I need the air mouse functionality: you move the tool and the mouse position change on the screen.

I did plug the usb receiver on the pc, but nothing happens.
How can I debug it to check if a driver for it exists ?

I know you can do the same now with an android tv working as remote, but keeping a phone on hand for 2-3 hours starts to be heavy!

Comment: The more unbranded, the more generic; the more generic the better supported. All of those are "plug'n'play".

Comment: well.. while I agry with you in general terms, as I wrote, I did plug the receiver and nothing happened.